# Rendering react component after api response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropbox-api

I have a react component that I wish to populate with images using the Dropbox api. The api part works fine, but the component is rendered before the data comes through & so the array is empty. How can I delay the rendering of the component until it has the data it needs?

```
var fileList = [];
var images = [];
var imageSource = [];

class Foo extends React.Component {

 render(){
  dbx.filesListFolder({path: ''})
  .then(function(response) {
   fileList=response.entries;
   for(var i=0; i<fileList.length; i++){
    imageSource.push(fileList[0].path_lower);
   }
   console.log(imageSource);
   })

  for(var a=0; a<imageSource.length; a++){
   images.push(<img key={a} className='images'/>);
  }

  return (
   <div className="folioWrapper">
    {images}
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would only mount that component once you have the images. So whoever mounts this component (the parent), should fetch the images then mount the component.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing all of that work inside your `render` method. Where are you changing the state? The component renders after updating the state.

Answer (score 40):

Changes:

**1.** Don't do the api call inside render method, use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method for that.

**[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)**:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

**2.** Define the `imageSource` variable in state array with initial value `[]`, once you get the response update that using **[setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)**, it will automatically re-render the component with updated data.

**3.** Use the state array to generate the ui components in render method.

**4.** To hold the rendering until you didn't get the data, put the condition inside `render` method check the length of `imageSource` array if length is zero then `return null`.

Write it like this:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            imageSource: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        dbx.filesListFolder({path: ''})
          .then((response) => {
              let fileList = response.entries;
              this.setState({
                  imageSource: fileList
              });
          })
    }

    render(){
        if(!this.state.imageSource.length)
            return null;

        let images = this.state.imageSource.map((el, i) => (
            <img key={i} className='images' src={el.path_lower} />
        ))

        return (
            <div className="folioWrapper">
                {images}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to bind set state to the function inside the promise

Answer (score 6):

You should be using your component's state or props so that it will re-render when data is updated. The call to Dropbox should be done outside of the `render` method or else you'll be hitting the API every time the component re-renders. Here's an example of what you could do.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageSource: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    dbx.filesListFolder({ path: '' }).then(function(response) {
      const fileList = response.entries;

      this.setState({
        imageSource: fileList.map(file => file.path_lower);
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="folioWrapper">
        {this.state.imageSource.map((image, i) => <img key={i} className="images" src={image} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If there are no images yet, it'll just render an empty `div` this way.

Comment: I think this code won't work, because the Binding is missing.

Comment: @cloud_traveler what do you mean? What binding is missing?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should be using the [component's state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and not using globally defined variables.

So to avoid showing the component with an empty array of images, you'll need to apply a conditional "loading" class on the component and remove it when the array is no longer empty.

Comment: That's the issue I'm struggling to understand - how to enable the component to _know_ when the array is no longer empty.

Comment: See Mayank Shukla answer.