# How to access variable values inside componentWillMount() in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-lifecycle

I'm assigning values inside my `componentWillMount` like shown in below

```
componentWillMount() {
    /*this.props.fetchMetaData(this.props.url);*/
    axios.get(`https://api.microlink.io/?url=${this.props.url}`)
        .then(res => {
            this.metaData = res;
            console.log("99999999999 ", this.metaData.data.data);
            this.image = this.metaData.data.data.image.url;
            this.title = this.metaData.data.data.title;
            this.description = this.metaData.data.data.description;
            this.metaurl = this.metaData.data.data.url;
            console.log("title ", this.title);
        });
}
```

And i'm trying to show the values inside my `render()` as follows.

```
render() {
    console.log("title ", this.title);
    return (
        <div>
            <a className="previewUrlContainer float_left unchange_div border"
               href={metaurl}
               target="_blank">
                <img className="previewImage margin_bottom10px" src={this.image}></img>
                <div className="margin_bottom10px font_bold">{this.title}</div>
                <div className="margin_bottom10px medium_font">{this.description}</div>
                <div className="margin_bottom10px small_font">{this.metaurl}</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But I get undefined values even though I've checked all the values inside `componentWillMount`. How can i use the values inside `componentWillMount`within `render()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911012/rendering-react-component-after-api-response

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a async call in `componentWillMount`, you response is only ready after the initial render and when you just set the class variables a re-render is not called and hence the result is not getting reflected in UI. You should use state to store the data. Also you must have your API call in componentDidMount lifecycle. You can check this for more details

[Use componentWillMount or componentDidMount lifecycle functions for async request in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392910/use-componentwillmount-or-componentdidmount-lifecycle-functions-for-async-reques/47393005#47393005)

```
state= {
    image: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    metaurl: ''
}
componentDidMount() {


    /*this.props.fetchMetaData(this.props.url);*/
    axios.get(`https://api.microlink.io/?url=${this.props.url}`)
        .then(res => {

            this.setState({
                image: res.data.data.image.url;
                title: res.data.data.title;
                description : res.data.data.description;
                metaurl : res.data.data.url;
           })

        })

    }

render() {

    return (

        <div>

            <a className="previewUrlContainer float_left unchange_div border"
               href={metaurl}
               target="_blank">

                <img className="previewImage margin_bottom10px" src={this.state.image}></img>
                <div className="margin_bottom10px font_bold">{this.state.title}</div>
                <div className="margin_bottom10px medium_font">{this.state.description}</div>
                <div className="margin_bottom10px small_font">{this.state.metaurl}</div>


            </a>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should store those data in the state. Call `setState` in `componentWillMount` (recommended to change to `componentDidMount` for clearer intention).

Demo:

```
class App {
  state = {
    res: null,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(...).then(res => this.setState({res}))
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.res)}</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Could someone please explain why everyone is recommending componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount in this kind of situations?

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed `componentWillMount` should not have side effects: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount. These lifecycle methods are getting replaced by React Hooks btw.