# Render after API call ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

[Alexnm](https://github.com/alexnm/react-ssr/) Shows the terribly disgusting architecture you must provide to simply have a server wait before an API call is complete before a server responds to a client.

He shows that you must first document each component of your entire app in a single, non-hierarchical flat list, then filter through **every single component** to see if a component has a API "data-requirement" for **every single request**, then store the output of that API request in a **global** *redux* object (also disgusting), then somehow pass that back to the object in the hopes it doesn't collide with other requests.

This is because ReactJS "[lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911012/rendering-react-component-after-api-response)" hooks aren't *actually* lifecycle hooks at all, and is instead ["fast and free" (and fun)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337165/react-render-is-being-called-before-componentdidmount).

I don't really care for any of these libraries, ES[xyz] syntaxes, and strange philosophies, but what I would like to do is return the an http response **after** and API call is made, i.e.

```
render() {
    // do an API call.
    // return a response.
}
```

I've seen uses if `fetch(xyz).then(() => {})` and so many other colorful brackets and functions where I'm not totally sure where parameters go in or where they go out, and I can't seem to figure out how to simply **hold off the next line of code** before the previous line of code is complete. In `then(() => {})`, which is syntaticly beautiful, I'm unable to return a value in any way at all. It's called a *function*, but I'm having difficulty achieving anything other than a side *side-effect*, and am unable to *return* a result of any kind.

Does anyone know how to make the `render()`, on it's own, wait for an API call?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer (hence the comment), but - you really, really don't want `render` to block on API calls! That's going to hang the page and generally make your application feel sluggish. The idea is that you call `setState` on your component within the `then` of your `fetch` (which runs after the HTTP request has completed) to re-render your component once the data has arrived. Then you can render a loading spinner/placeholders/some big bold text saying "*IT'S LOADING I SWEAR*" in the meantime.

Comment: Relevant section of the docs, if you've not already stumbled across it: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: So for context, I'm doing server-side rendering (for SEO reasons). I've tried doing an  API call in `componentDidMount` (and others) and setting state in there, but from logging, I've discovered `render` is called before `componentDidMount` is done. `render` reads the state, but the state isn't set yet.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is here, it reads to me like basically a rant, firstly about some technicalities of React (that I'm not too familiar with so can't really comment if they're fair or not), followed by a rant against Promises, it seems just because they're asynchronous? While I sympathise that asynchronous programming is quite hard, it's 1) unavoidable in JS unless you want to give users a truly horrible experience and 2) promises, once you get used to them, make it much easier than it ever was before. (`async/await`, which is still promise-based, makes it even easier)

Comment: @Display name: Ah, I see - in that case, you probably don't want to be fetching the data within the lifecycle hooks (unless you want the request to run again on the client). Fetch the data *before* rendering the component (e.g. in your server's request handler), and pass it in to your component as props. [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle) is a nice pre-baked package for doing this (without the waters being muddied by Redux, etc) - hopefully it'll give you some inspiration.

Comment: I try to understand your problem, but I can't.

Comment: Are the lifecycle methods even called during SSR? The only pre-rendering I've done with React has been with static rendering, so maybe it's different, but in that situation `componentDidMount` and the rest don't get called until the page is loaded in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As for philosophies - you may want to read more on flux patterns - which were architectural design principles conjoured at Facebook. The efforts were to handle global state in a Single Page Application, or SPA.

Per your current syntax issue - you may utilize promises with arrow functions. Promises were introduced in ES6 as a solution for handling asynchronous requests cleaner.

Using your example `fetch(xyz).then(() => {})` one may execute requests synchronously by:

```
render() {
   Promise.resolve(fetch(xyz))
   .then((response) => {
      // Do something with this response - for example..
      if (response.data) {
         axios.get("http://google.com")
         .then((response) => {

         console.log(response.data);

         })
         .catch((err) => {

         // Do something with this error
         console.log(err);
         })
      }
   })
})

return (
    <div>

    </div>
)
}
```

I won't get into time complexities - but the above solution will fire off the `fetch(xyz)` request, then once that requet has completed - we fire off the next request. This is called promise chaining - more information may be found here: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

If your goal is to simply make a call and use the data once the component has rendered, or mounted, you may do something cleaner and react friendly (non blocking) like the example below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Example extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: ''
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
   Promise.resolve(fetch(xyc))
   .then((response.data) => {
       this.setState({
         data:response.data
    });
   })
};

render() {
  const data = this.state

  return (
    {data} 
  )
}
```